# No coercion operator is defined between types 1

Tags: c#

```
 var cpaclassids = FetchProductTypes(ids);
 var cpaclids = string.Join(",", cpaclassids);            
 var query = (from x in partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery() join y in partRepository.GetPartsQuery() on x.PartId equals y.Id
                                      join z in partProductTypeReposiotry.GetPartProductTypesQuery() on x.PartId equals z.PartId where y.IsSkipped == 0 && (y.IsDisabled != "Y" || y.IsDisabled == null) && z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate && x.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) select new { x }).Cast<PartJoinTable>();

 var predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
 predicate1 = predicate1.And(x => cpaclassids.Contains(x.ProductTypeId.ToString()));

 int lst = query.Where(predicate1).Select(x => x.PartId).Distinct().ToList().Count(); // on this line
```

Exception details:

> No coercion operator is defined between types '<>f__AnonymousType5`1[PartDomain.Model.Models.PartJoinTable]' and 'PartDomain.Model.Models.PartJoinTable'.'

The exception is displayed when I try to get the count in the lst

Comment: Which line is throwing this exception?

Comment: int lst = query.Where(predicate1).Select(x => x.PartId).Distinct().ToList().Count();this line is throwing exception

Comment: public IQueryable<PartJoinTable> GetPartJoinQuery()
        {
            return Set;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select new { x }
```

is returning an anonymous type with a `x` property of type `PartJoinTable`. As expected, that anonymous type can't be converted to `PartJoinTable`.

The fix is to change it to:

```
select x
```

to instead return the `PartJoinTable` entity **itself**.

```
 var cpaclassids = FetchProductTypes(ids);
 var cpaclids = string.Join(",", cpaclassids);            
 var query = (from x in partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery() join y in partRepository.GetPartsQuery() on x.PartId equals y.Id
                                      join z in partProductTypeReposiotry.GetPartProductTypesQuery() on x.PartId equals z.PartId where y.IsSkipped == 0 && (y.IsDisabled != "Y" || y.IsDisabled == null) && z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate && x.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) select x).Cast<PartJoinTable>();

 var predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
 predicate1 = predicate1.And(x => cpaclassids.Contains(x.ProductTypeId.ToString()));

 int lst = query.Where(predicate1).Select(x => x.PartId).Distinct().ToList().Count();
```